# Efficient way to parse SOAP web service response

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

I have a SOAP web service that generates a response in XML format. Would like to render this response to the web page. I am currently issuing web service requests on a timely basis, via ajax calls.

Is there any preferred way to parse the xml response? The response can contain arrays of objects. What is the most appropriate way to render this response to the web page? If I have a html table, does it mean for each cell, I would have to have a "div /div" to update each individual field? This seems very inefficient and codes can be very ugly. Or do I have to follow what this web site does: (http://www.phpeveryday.com/articles/jQuery-AJAX-and-XML-P970.html ), writing html codes in Javascript? My concern is if I use the latter method, it might mean I am exposing my schema.

I am currently using spring mvc for my controller.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Controller request --> Ws request --> Ws response --> Controller resposne?

Comment: I don't fully understand how to use the technology myself, but I worked on a project where we used JAXB to generate POJOs from our schemas.  We used the web service to return the POJOs to our conroller and then iterated through the class instances, creating JSON objects.  We returned the string-ified JSON object to the AJAX call and then rendered the data as needed.

Comment: Why not unmarshall the objects to xml string, therefore your ajax can print them on the page directly